# React onClick on stateless component

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to fire an onClick on a react component. The event fires if I use

```
<button onClick={()=>this.goToPage('next')}>Next Page</button>
```

If I use the same method on a stateless component, it doesn't fire:

```
<PageButton onClick={()=>this.goToPage('next')}>Next Page</PageButton>
```

Why this is not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because what you are defining is a custom component. Note, that everything that you provide to the custom component is considered as props. So, your `onClick` method is also provided as props. Essentially you'll be required to do -

```
<PageButton onClick={()=>this.goToPage('next')}>Next Page</PageButton>
```

and in your `<PageButton />` component -

```
<button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Next Page</button>
```

if you know what `props` you are providing to this component and not providing any unnecessary props, you can even spread the `props` object, like -

```
<button {...this.props}>Next Page</button>
```

**Note** - If you have other props to provide to this component as well, kindly refrain from using this method, as this will result in many unrecognized function warnings.

PS: Even if you write

```
<PageButton style={{backgroundColor: 'red}}>Next Page</PageButton>
```

it won't work because, this is treated as a `prop`. You'll need to handle the style prop in the render method of this `<PageButton/>` component

Answer (score 1):

This does not work on a stateless component because the onClick is considered as a prop rather a event listener , you should implement.
For example inside PageButton you should implement something like this

`render(){
       return <div onClick={()=>this.props.onClick('next')}/>
      }`